# Check if only certain values exist in a list (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
A = [x,y,z]
```

and I need help with writing a code in Python that returns `True` if any combination of x or y or z is in the list, but returns `False` if any other variables outside of A is in the list.

Example:

```
B = [x]  (return True)
B = [l] (return False)
B = [x,z] (return True)
B = [x,y,z,l] (return False)
```

Comment: You don't actually have a question there.  Please read how to ask

Answer (score 1):

You can make a set from your list, and check if the elements are its subset

```
sA = set(list)
sE = set(elements)
check = sE <= sA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def b(list_of_b):
    A = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    for i in list_of_b:
        if i in A:
            return True
    return False
print(b(['X','Y']))
```

This may help Happy Coding